# How does propagation relate to switching time of a circuit?

Tags: propagation, optimization

I have this circuit:

[image]

I know how to measure the propagation delay between a certain input and output. In my homework, I am  required to optimize the area of each transistor. One point that occurs to me is that I can optimize my circuit in aspect of switching time of the whole circuit. So my question is as follows: how does switching time of a circuit relate to propagation delay? Is it just a simple addition of propagation delay of each input? Also, how does the area affect the propagation delay? Is it linearly?

Comment: You will need to precisely define what you mean by "switching time of the whole circuit". This is not common terminology in digital systems design.

Comment: The switching frequency would be limited by: \$1/2 t{_d}_{,max}\$ and this prop. delay  \$t{_d}\$ would itself be the average of the hi-to-low and low-to-high prop. delays along the critical path. If both of these values are similar, you get the least delay along the path. I would start with one inverter to understand this concept before working on a complicated circuit.

Comment: You need to learn about the **logical effort** method to solve problems like this and the similar ones for calculating propagation delays of digital circuits. It is somewhat pointless to limit the introduction to this method to only the circuit of your question. Take a Digital Circuits course like this (http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icdesign/ee141_f05/) to learn The Method of Logical Effort (http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icdesign/ee141_f05/resources.html).

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, by switching time i mean the time for a circuit to be turned on(Or can i say the overall propagation delay?)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the time required for a change in an input signal to cause a change in an output signal then yes, it is just the sum of the propagation delays of the gates and wires in the signal path from input to output.

Increasing the width of the transistors does not necessarily reduce the propagation delay, because you are increasing the capacitance at the same time that you increase drive current. This is a non-trivial optimization problem in practice because you usually want to **reduce** transistor sizes to save silicon area (translation: cost of manufacturing) and reduce power consumption.